# Proving that a specific function isn't continuous

Tags: calculus, functions

Assume the following:

$d(x)$ is the Dirichlet Function,

$f(0) = 1$,

$f(0)$ is continuous at $x = 0$, and

$g(x) = d(x)f(x)$.

I need to prove (in two ways: with $\delta$ and $\epsilon$, and with arithmetic of limits) that $g(x)$ is not continuous at $x_0=0$.
I've tried a lot with $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ but unsuccessfully. I'd like you to help me with the proof.

Comment: Use the fact that $g(0)=1, g(x)=0$ if $x$ is irrational and that for every $\delta>0$ there is an irrational $x$ such that $|x|<\delta$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that since $\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)$ exists
$$
\limsup_{x\to 0}d(x)f(x)=f(0)\limsup_{x\to 0}d(x)=1
$$
but
$$
\liminf_{x\to0}d(x)f(x)=f(0)\liminf_{x\to0}d(x) = 0.
$$
If you want to use $\varepsilon,\delta$, use the discontinuity of $d$, i.e. there exists $1>\varepsilon>0$ such that for every $\delta>0$ there exists $x$ with $|x|<\delta$ but $|d(x)-1|\geqslant \varepsilon$. On the other hand, $f$ is continuous so $|f(x)-1|<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ provided $|x|$ is small enough.

You get
$$\begin{aligned}|d(x)f(x)-1|&=|d(x)f(x)-f(x)+f(x)-1|\\
&\geqslant|f(x)||d(x)-1|-|f(x)-1|\\ &\geqslant |f(x)|\varepsilon-\frac{\varepsilon}{3}\\
&\geqslant\left(1-\frac{\varepsilon}{3}\right)\varepsilon-\frac{\varepsilon}{3}\geqslant\frac{\varepsilon}{3}.
\end{aligned}$$
Can you finish from here?

Comment: Yes I just need to say that we found one Epsilon that shows that the function is discontinus right? Thank you.

Comment: Right. And observe that the non-zero value $f(0)=1\ne 0$ is crucial for the argument (otherwise for example the function $f=x^2$ would be a counterexample and moreover a function that is discontinuous everywhere but continuous only in 0 and even differentiable in that single point). You are very welcome.