# Discontinuity of the function at a point by the Cauchy definition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, proof-writing

In the very beginning, I'm going to refer to similar posts dealing with proofs of continuity(discontinuity) of a function at a point or on an open interval:

[Proving that a specific function isn't continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/886900/721644)

[Help with epsilon-delta proof that 1/(x^2) is continuous at a point.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/751156/721644)

My problem:

> Prove that $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$
>   $$f:=\begin{cases}3^x,\;\;\;\;\;x<0\\3^{-x+1},x\geq0\end{cases}$$ is
>   discontinuous at $x=0$ by the Cauchy definition.

By the definition (source: [Continuity &Limits/Neprekidnost i limesi](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/nastava/analiza/files/lim2.pdf)):

Let $I\subseteq\mathbb R$ be an open interval. Function $f$ is continuous at a point $c\in I$ iff:
$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0) s.t. x\in I,|x-c|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(c)|<\varepsilon$$
Since I have to prove discontinuity at $x=0$, I negated the statement and plugged $x=0$ into it:
$$(\exists\varepsilon>0)(\forall\delta>0)s.t.x\in I ,|x|<\delta\;\land\;|f(x)-f(0)|\geq\varepsilon$$

> $$\iff(\exists\varepsilon>0)(\forall\delta>0)s.t.x\in
>  I,|x|<\delta\;\land\;|f(x)-3|\geq\varepsilon$$

and

> $$x\in\langle-\delta,\delta\rangle$$

I'm a bit confused because I have only seen such proofs of Dirichlet's function and certain step-functions.
First thing I did was finding $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=1\;\&\;\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x)=3$$ and we cannot extend the function by some continuous function from that point.
Then I decided to solve the inequality to find sufficiently small $\varepsilon$, but I didn't get far from what I already had:$$|f(x)-3|\geq\varepsilon$$
What should I do next if the function is defined by $2$ formulae on $2$ disjoint intervals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limit $L$ that works. Suppose we take some possible limit $L < 2.$ No matter how small $\delta > 0$ is, there are points with $-\delta < x < 0$ such that $f(x) > \frac{5}{2},$ so violates the limit condition for any $0 < \varepsilon < \frac{1}{2}$

Similar for $L \geq 2,$ switching to $0 < x < \delta$

Comment: Can I conclude that at the end of the proof by Cauchy definition? Is it concise enough and legitimate in the context of this peculiar definition?

Comment: @VerkhovtsevaKatya yes, this is correct. I think you are getting trouble from trying to expand everything into logic symbols, also you don't have a good visual sense. I recommend printing pdf's of graph paper (or buy graph paper) and making a habit of plotting the simpler functions you come across; telling a computer to plot something and staring at the result is not the same https://incompetech.com/graphpaper/

Comment: thank you! I appreciate your advice.

Comment: @VerkhovtsevaKatya back again. People my age graphed functions by hand. Meanwhile, note that "belletristic" is not a noun, it is an adjective. The original phrase: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belles-lettres

Answer (score 0):

This is a long comment.

---

Just to clarify the negation of logical statement is wrong. You should emphasize that there exists some $x$ with $|x|<\delta$ such that $|f(x) - f(0)|\geq \epsilon$. Your negation seems to imply that this holds for all $x$ with $|x|<\delta$. Unless you are an expert in logic, it is better to explain / write definitions involving $\epsilon, \delta$ in your language of communication. Too much symbolism is a sure way to mess up your understanding.

Comment: thank you for commenting. Some things written by our assistant are suspicious, but therefore I ask. Thank you once again. I have an exam today so every feedback is helpful to me.